# $.post() sometimes takes 2 submits to send the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've researched for a couple of days, but not been able to find a fix for this. Here's the issue:

I have a form that submits a message to be processed/inserted into a db. The form uses $.post() to submit the message.

Sometimes it works just fine, but once in a while (completely random, it seems) -- I will have to press the submit button twice to get the data to go through. The first time I press the submit button, it "appears" to have submitted, since the form clears like normal, etc -- but the data isn't sent. If I then click the submit button again (without entering anything in the input), it will send the message that I tried to submit one click ago.  I hope this makes sense.

In other words, most of the time I can enter a message, click submit 1 time, and it works fine. But randomly I will have to click submit more than once to get the data to actually submit.

On occasion, the "glitch" will happen more than one time in a row. When this happens, I have to hit submit over and over until all messages have been sent. It's almost like they are getting queued somehow?

Here is the function that I'm using to submit the data:

```
function postMsg() {
    $.post("index.php", {
        message: $("[name='message']").val()
    });
    document.m.message.focus();
    return false;
}
```

And the form tag I'm using:

```
<form class="form-inline"  id="m"  name="m" method="post" onSubmit="postMsg();clear_form();return false">
```

And just in case it's needed for some reason, the clear_form() function that I'm using:

```
function clear_form() {
    document.getElementById('message').value = '';
}
```

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated.

UPDATED to include the function provided by Crone -- it works, but still has the issue of needing to submit multiple times before the data goes through:

```
    jQuery("#m").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

jQuery.post("index.php", {
    message: jQuery("[name='message']").val()
});

document.m.message.focus();

clear_form();
});
```

UPDATE - Added the function that I use to load the messages in the display . This is called onLoad, and when a new message is submitted, so that it will grab and show the new data.

```
function loadMainDisplay(){
    $( "#innercontrols" ).load( "includes/controls.php" );
scrollToBottom();
}
```

The "controls.php" is just a file that grabs the messages from the mysql database and echos them out in the proper format.

At the top of my index.php (where the functions/form are located), I have a check to see if any input has been submitted using an Input class, it looks like this:

```
if(Input::exists()){
    $message = Input::get('message');
... validate and insert into db if ok
}
```

If you would like a link to the actual page to see the issue first hand, let me know and I will send a private message with the link.

Comment: You should really be using more jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('form [type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

jQuery.post("index.php", {
    message: jQuery("[name='message']").val()
});

document.m.message.focus();

clear_form();
});
```

Version with "Enter" button support:

```
jQuery("form").on('submit', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

jQuery.post("index.php", {
    message: jQuery("[name='message']").val()
});

document.m.message.focus();

clear_form();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot. I see that it's an on click function,  will that also work if they submit the form using the enter button, or will I have to add/modify for that?

Comment: @MikeRoberts - no it won't, that's why you should generally always listen for the `submit` event, as in `$('#m').on('submit', function() {...`

Comment: Added version for "Enter" button support.

Comment: I'll give that a shot here and report back shortly, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've added the version with enter button support, and It works, but it has the same issue as the code I was using before, although it appears to happen more often. At least half of the submissions take 2 clicks (or "enters") before they go through.  I'm really scratching my head on this one

Comment: Ok. Then provide more code that you have on the page with this form. Probably other events are making such problem.

Comment: I added more of the code, and can also send a link to the page so you can see it firsthand, if you want. @Crone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78824/discussion-between-mike-roberts-and-crone).

Comment: I sent the link in a chat for you

Comment: Added the code you sent, with a 50ms setTimeout to loadMainDisplay() and it seems to be able to keep up now. It'll work until I can learn websockets. Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: Great. :) I'm glad that I could help you.